# How do I redirect to multi-lingual content in my Gatbsy website?

Tags: gatsby

I'm working on a multi-lingual site, where the default language is english and there are two other language options (Japanese and Chinese).

The website needs to be able to detect the users language preference and automatically re-direct to that language version of the website. The preference is primarily fetched from localStorage. If there is no preference in localStorage yet, we look to the browser language.

The current approach is the below code, which is ran in the onInitialClientRender function inside my gatsby-node file.

```js
export const languages: { [key: string]: string } = {
  'en-us': `English`, // EN
  'zh-tw': `繁體中文`, // ZH
  'ja-jp': `日本語`, // JA
};

export function parseLng(lng: string) {
  const fullLangName = Object.keys(languages).find((item) =>
    item.includes(lng),
  );
  // Return early if a fullLang name cannot be found
  // Its likely that the users language is not supported
  if (!fullLangName) return;

  return fullLangName;
}

export const getStorageLng = (): string | null => localStorage.getItem(`lng`);
export const setStorageLng = (lng: string): void =>
  localStorage.setItem(`lng`, lng || `en-us`);

export function getBrowserLng(): string | undefined {
  // find language preference in localStorage
  const lngInStorage = getStorageLng();
  if (lngInStorage && lngInStorage in languages) return lngInStorage;

  // find the browser language
  const navigatorLng = navigator.language.substring(0, 2);
  const lng = parseLng(navigatorLng);
  return lng;
}

export function getPageLang(): string | null {
  const urlLang = window.location.pathname;

  const urlLangString = urlLang.slice(1, 6);
  if (urlLangString in languages) return urlLangString;

  return null;
}

function isLngMatch(targetLng: 'en' | 'ja' | 'zh', lng: string) {
  return lng.slice(0, 2) === targetLng;
}

export function redirect() {
  const targetLng = getBrowserLng();
  const pageLng = getPageLang();

  // redirect to the route for the browser language
  // Only if the user has a language preference other than English
  if (
    targetLng &&
    !isLngMatch(`en`, targetLng) &&
    !pageLng &&
    targetLng !== pageLng
  ) {
    window.location.pathname = `/${targetLng}${window.location.pathname}`;
  }
}

export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
  redirect();
};
```

It seems to work on my desktop and mobile browsers, however some users are reporting that this logic is creating an infinite redirect loop on their mobile device.

Unfortunately, the fact that I cannot replicate this issue on my end is making debugging the issue difficult.

We know that this line is causing the redirect loop:
`` window.location.pathname = `/${targetLng}${window.location.pathname}`; ``

The baffling thing is that the redirect keeps going to the same English language version of the page, as though there is no targetLng. But the if statement stipulates that this line of code should only run if there is a targetLng.

Has anyone ever ran into these issues before? Is there an alternative 'best practice' approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is line
`targetLng && !isLngMatch(`en`, targetLng) && !pageLng && targetLng !== pageLng`

Not the changing of pathname which is the redirect. That then causes a new rerender.

I tried to go back through and make sense of maybe where the issue could lie, without much luck, maybe the problem is the problem itself. Too much going on. It being a random issue with some mobile made me think of a localstorage issue.

Having had a look I think the more elegant solution is to use https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n - see demo which uses a [defaultLangKey](https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n/blob/master/packages/gatsby-starter-default-i18n/src/data/languages.js). Trimming back logic and avoid the random bug.

Sorry I couldn't be more help, I can see the frustration with this one.